# wordpress admin-ajax.php return secuity page

Tags: ajax, wordpress, security

I'm trying to get information from the database via an ajax POST in a modal window.  The first time I try (either via ajax or inputting in the URL - http://map4help.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=show_ajax_modal - in the browser) I am prompted to solve an equation for access, eg

```
(9 + 6) * 1 = ---
```

If it is solved, it works, but I do not want it displayed for all users.

I am stuck, need help, thanks.

Comment: What plugins do you have enabled?  That doesn't look like standard WordPress functionality.

Comment: I'm disable all plugins, nothing happens, all as before

Comment: I trying create new clean wordpress site in subfolder, as before it whant to solve an equation for access. Maby it's problem not in WP ?

Comment: SOLVED! It was server option in test mode.
Named as:
"Protection from password guessing, recommending for JOOMLA, WORDPRESS"
I disable that, and all working now.